# No ObservableObject of type User found

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to understand @EnvironmentObject better so I wrote sample code below to replicate the issue i am facing

This is the class where i declare the array which needs to be accessed in multiple locations and be displayed and updated in ContentView

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var array = [String]()

    func diplayName(name: String){
        self.array.append(name)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to append my array in another class. Something like the below code

```
class myTests: ObservableObject {
    @EnvironmentObject var user:User

    func diplayMyName(name: String){
        self.user.array.append(name)
    }
}
```

When I call displayMyName function in myTests class i get an Error message as below

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type User found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for User may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

This is how my contentView looks like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user:User
    var testing = myTests()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(user.array, id: \.self){ x in
                Text(x)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.user.diplayName(name: "Name1")
//                self.testing.diplayMyName(name: "Name2")
            }){
                Text("Call Function")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i declare my environment object in scene delegate

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(User())
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand why am i getting the error when i append the published array from myTests class. Thank you.

---

### UPDATE

To work around my issue i did the following adjustments 
I returned an array in myTests class

```
class myTests {
    var ar = [String]()

    func displayMyName() -> [String] {
        ar.removeAll()
        ar.append(contentsOf: ["Name2", "Name3"])
        return ar
    }
}
```

And added it to the array in ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user : User
    var testing = myTests()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            List(user.array, id: \.self){ x in
                Text(x)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.user.array.append(contentsOf: self.testing.displayMyName())
            }){
                Text("Call Function")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@EnvironmentObject` usage in `myTest` is invalid. Why do you put it there?

Comment: How can i access and append array within myTest ?

Comment: Just assign via property or pass in constructor arguments.

Comment: I will try that. So I only use the @EnvironmentObject where i need to observe the changes and read them, is this right?

Comment: Your code works fine when I stick it in a playground. I suspect that you're creating a `ContentView` somewhere else without including `environmentObject()`.

Comment: The error occurs when i call the commented line, appending “Name2” to the array by calling the function in myTests class